# Email Button on Account record in the Action Bar in Lightning Mobile App

Tags: email, page-layout, account, mobile, quickaction

I can see the Email button in desktop, however in the mobile App, i can't see the Email button in the Action bar. Please refer to screen shots. Am i missing something, or the ability to send Email from an Account record is not available on Mobile App?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000334558&type=1&mode=1), Some things to keep in mind:

- When sending emails from the native device, you can't use Salesforce
  Email Templates found in the full site.
- Emails sent are not sent out of Salesforce, and so they are not
  tracked or logged in the same way as other emails from the full site.
- Sending an email is not automatically added to the record in
  Salesforce for Android and iOS.
- The email button cannot be disabled, but will not display if the
  record does not contain an email address.
- **The Send Email action (standard productivity action) is supported on
  Contacts, Leads, Users, and Person Accounts. to learn more, [please
  review Salesforce Mobile App Action Bar](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=actionbar_overview.htm&type=5).**
- Custom Object Specific Send Email Actions are not supported and will
  not appear in the Salesforce App.
- [Additional information on differences](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=limits_mobile_sf1_service.htm&type=5) between the Salesforce App and
  desktop experience

Also see, [Add the 'Send Email' action to Cases in the Salesforce for Android and iOS](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Salesforce1-Adding-the-Send-Email-action-to-Cases&type=1&language=en_US)